# expression() within foreach %dopar%

Tags: r, foreach, snow

I'm trying to include an `expression()` in `foreach() %dopar%`. This `expression()` will be used to simulate an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process via the `Sim.DiffProc` package within the `foreach() %dopar%` call.

However the parallel computing nodes doesn't seem to recognise the variables specified in `expression()` and I got the following error `Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'OUTheta' not found"`

Anybody have any ideas how to solve the issue? Many thanks in advance!

My code:

```
library(Sim.DiffProc)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)


cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

a = foreach(i = 1:2, .packages = c('Sim.DiffProc')) %dopar% {
  OUMu = 1
  OUTheta = 1
  OUSigma = 1
  f = expression(OUTheta * (OUMu - x))
  g = expression(OUSigma)
  sim = Sim.DiffProc::snssde1d(drift = f, diffusion = g, x0 = 0, N = 10, T = 1, method = 'euler', M = 1)
  return(sim$X)
}
```

Comment: Look at the source code of the package, it looks they are not tracking the environment of the expression properly so it won't work when your variables are not defined in the global environment. You could file a bug report at https://github.com/acguidoum/Sim.DiffProc/issues if you like.

Comment: @MrFlick, Thanks for the info - I've just reported the issue there https://github.com/acguidoum/Sim.DiffProc/issues/5